# Find and Replace Javascript Needs to pull values from an excel sheet, loop though, and output

Tags: javascript, excel

I have a script that replaces multiple words within the sentence.

Here is the current script:
http://jsfiddle.net/2z3b4/

I would like to take this one step further and be able to loop through a list of replacement words in an excel sheet. the sentence will change several words, so ideally I will need to pull words from multiple columns

i.e. word1 to be replaced = column A1
     word2 to be replaced = column B1

It will then begin to move to the next column

```
 word1 to be replaced = column A2
 word2 to be replaced = column B2
```

After it pulls and replaces these values I would like it to return output on a page.

a.) How would I pull values from an excel sheet?
b.) How would I get the excel sheet to loop through all of the columns and then stop when completed??
c.) How do I return the output on a separate page?

Comment: Did you do any research on reading excel with JavaScript? If it is a CSV file, there are no issues. If it is not csv, than you will need to find something else to really process it.

Comment: Is the web browser your execution environment? Do you mean separate **web** page?

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to consider using a different language to Javascript if you need to take values from an Excel sheet - perhaps use VBA within Excel instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with javascript.. and it's not that hard as long as it's an excel 2007+ document. Just lots of steps and ambiguity. If it's 2003 or below you might have a bit of a problem, as I'm not sure of any JS libs that can really help with reading in a binary file. Anyway...

Get [jszip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip). This lets you unzip Excel 2007+ files (really, all an Excel 2007+ file contains is a bunch of XML files)

If you don't care about IE, and you expect your client browsers to be fairly up to date you can use the FileReader api (look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader). If you do care about IE, I'm sure there is a flash project out there that will read the content of a file and send it to javascript via externalInterface. Or you could just rig it up yourself. Or perhaps you could 'upload' the file in an iframe and have an 'echo' just print back the contents of the file base64 encoded, which you can then pump into jszip.

Once you're able to read the contents of the file, use jszip to open the file contents, probably with `new JSZip(zipDataBinary, {base64:false});`

Since you're just replacing text, you can most likely just focus in on the sharedStrings.xml file.

```
zipFile = new JSZip(zipDataBinary, {base64:false});
var sharedStringFile= zipFile.file(/sharedStrings\.xml/);
```

Now, easy peasy -

```
var newData = sharedStringFile.asText().replace(/* and all the stuff you want replaced, or in a loop, or whatever.. */);
```

The important thing to note here is that just about every single string in Excel 2007+ files is held in this sharedStrings.xml file - they did some work to try and optimize the size of the excel files, and string data is one of the most commonly duplicated pieces of data in a spreadsheet. So, if you've got a cell A1 that has "this is a cell!", it's actually represented as

```
<c r="A1" t="s">
    <v>1</v>
</c>
```

The '1' is the index of the string in the sharedStrings.xml file. Anyhow..

After you're done,

```
zipFile.file(sharedStringFile.name, newData);
```

That'll update the content of the zip file. Now you can either send it to the server using some sort of 'echo' mechanism, or use 'Downloadify' to allow the user to download it. Or, if you want to actually read it in and show it on the page you can.. it's just a bit more involved.

Pack the zip file back up like so:

```
var sendThisDataSomewhere = zipFile.generate({base64: false});
```

And as a shameless plug, I figured out all this from the project I've been working on - http://excelbuilderjs.com/